# can't get the value of an input

Tags: javascript

I have a function in which I create an input like

```
tr = document.createElement("tr");
td1 = document.createElement("td");
td2 = document.createElement("td");
td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number:"));
td2.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
td2.setAttribute("id", "nr");
tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(tr);
```

Afterward, I want to get the value of it in another function with:

```
var nr = document.getElementById("nr").value;
```

it will know the nr element but the value is `undefined`

Comment: Because `td` elements don't have a value. You need the value of the `input`, not the `td`.

Comment: ups i am stupid, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @takendarkk said, the `<td>` tag doesn't have a value attribute.

In your code, define in a different variable the input creation so you can give it an id to referrer later, like this:

```
let tr = document.createElement("tr");
let td1 = document.createElement("td");
let td2 = document.createElement("td");
let input = document.createElement("input"); // Created input
input.setAttribute("id","nr"); // Given an id
td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number:"));
td2.appendChild(input); // Appended the input element previously created
tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(tr);
```

> As @AlexeyZelenin suggested, you should use `let` or `var` on variable definitions to prevent modifying another variable outside the current scope.

**Look at an example:**

Press the button to get the value of the input.

```js
const table = document.querySelector("table");

function createRow() {
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  let td1 = document.createElement("td");
  let td2 = document.createElement("td");
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("id","nr");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number:"));
  td2.appendChild(input);
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

createRow();

function showValue(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("nr").value);
}
```

```html
<table></table><button onclick="showValue()">Show value</button>
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `let` or `const` for every variable declaration, so they will not affect something out of scope.

Comment: @AlexeyZelenin totally accurate. Edited. I think I just got a small distraction on that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This line is setting the id of the `<td>`, not the appended child input element:

```
td2.setAttribute("id", "nr");
```